# Duplicate a print composer item

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is it possible to duplicate an item in the print composer?

I have two maps, and I'd like to add an attribute table to each map. It took me quite a while to set up the attribute table for the first map, and I'd rather not have to repeat the whole process for the second table. Is there a way to simply make a copy of the table?

Here are the things I've tried (unsuccessfully) so far:

- Copy and paste by selecting the table and hitting ctrl-C then ctrl-V. Ditto, using the copy and paste commands from the Edit menu.
- Duplicating the entire print composer, then dragging the table from the copy to the original. Turns out you can't drag an item from one print composer to another.
- Copy the table in the duplicate print composer, then paste into the original print composer.

Comment: you can duplicate the entire composer, if that will help

Comment: Duplicating the entire print composer is my fall-back solution, but it's not an ideal solution. Sometimes I need to have two tables for the same map.